# Moving a div so it includes my header bar

Tags: html, scroll, header, parallax

I've been trying to create a parallax header for the past couple of days, I've gotten pretty close but I have one last problem to solve. The div that includes the parallax header and all my content does not contain my header. This is a problem because it does no scroll with the rest of the page and looks like a sticky header which I don't want.

You can see my problem here:
https://crispimages.co/

I can not figure out how to order my divs while not breaking the parallax effect and keeping the scroll bar from behaving weirdly.

At the moment I have the parallax stuff in "et-main-area" but that does not include the nav bar. If I move the parallax id around it breaks the effect. I can't figure it out!

HTML:

```
<div id="et-main-area">
    <div id="parallax">
<div class="parralax__layer parallax__layer--back">
    <img src="https://crispimages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/layer_5.png">
</div>
<div  class="parralax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    <img src="https://crispimages.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/layer_6.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;

}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parralax__layer.parallax__layer--base{
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2.1);
}

.parralax__layer.parallax__layer--back{
transform: translateZ(-15px) scale(16.1);
}
```

Comment: Please share the code so we can better assist you.

Comment: I've updated with the relevant code, but because I'm working with a wordpress theme there is obviously a lot of other code going on on the page.

Comment: Understandable. Let me take a look.

Comment: So, quick question, You are trying to keep the header image at the top of the page while the rest of the page scrolls correct? Or are you wanting it to be more of a background that the content scrolls over?

Comment: It's a header not a background, the way it works at the moment is kind of correct it's just the nav bar is sticking with the view as you scroll down the page. I appreciate you helping me out :)

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to accomplish. I don't see and stickiness. If you highlight the background images they disappear as you scroll. The nav bar always stays in exact position. Are you wanting the nav bar to go away as you scroll? are you wanting the images to stay on the screen longer?

Comment: What browser are you using? The Nav bar is always at the top of the screen, which is not what I want. It should scroll with the rest of the content. On the browsers I have tested, Mozilla and Chrome, there are 2 scroll bars on the left. There should only be 1, its a problem with the divs for parallax and the nav bar but I cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Oh okay. Change overflow-y to hidden.I think that should fix your issue

Comment: Changing the overflow value for the parallax div that contains the header images and content means I can not scroll through my content. Changing it for the other div makes the site scroll strangely.

Comment: Just a sec, Playing around in dev tools

Comment: Can you undo what ever you did to your site real quick?

Comment: Sorry, was just having a play around. Should be back to how it was now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
#parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-right:-20px;
}
```

it will hide the extra scrollbar and is still responsive. That's the only way I could find to get rid of the extra scroll bar and not messing up any of the other styling.